# PHP PDO get auto_increment flag

Tags: php, pdo

Is there a way to check whether a column has been specified as auto_increment?
I know that the mysqli extension supports that.
However PDO's getColumnMeta() method does not provide this info

Is there any workaround available?

Thanks

Comment: You will need to select the data from `information_schema`, and in order to do that the user you are using to access MySQL will need the appropriate grants.

Comment: Why do you need that? auto-increment is an internal feature of which application level should know nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `cubrid_schema` function of PDO to know the description of table and its column.

OR

You can use the below code:

```
$q = $dbh->prepare("DESC tablename");
$q->execute();
$table_fields = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
```

[Reference site.](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.cubrid-schema.php)

Comment: [cubrid_schema()](http://es1.php.net/manual/en/function.cubrid-schema.php) does not seem to be a PDO function. It belongs to a PECL extension for a different DBMS engine. (The other solution is just fine IMHO.) - Not my downvote anyway.

Comment: cubrid_schema is not available. The other solution does not provide info on the column attributes. Just their name. Thanks anyway

Comment: @Thomas I don't know much more about the cubrid_schema but the second solution will working file as you can see the query `DESC table` will provide the full infomation.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario `cubrid_schema` is the function of PDO check the reference site given in the answer.

Comment: @BrokenHeartღ - You are right, there's a PDO function. Still, it belongs to the Cubrid driver. It isn't available for MySQL as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

You can query it from information schema like:

```
SELECT 
  EXTRA 
FROM 
  information_schema.columns 
WHERE 
  table_name = 'your_table_name' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'your_primary_key' 
  AND table_schema = DATABASE();
```

And you will get `auto_increment`.

> The Extra field contains any additional information that is available about a given column. The value is auto_increment for columns that have the AUTO_INCREMENT attribute and empty otherwise.

[INFORMATION_SCHEMA Tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/columns-table.html)